# .net web api RESTFul web service bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create a REST service to manage some DB tables, so because I'm new to C# and .NET I start by reading a tutorial, I came across this good starting point tut
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426769/Creating-a-REST-service-using-ASP-NET-Web-API

it shows how I can create some controller that handle in this case a simple tasks list, so I thought to create one controller for each table and implement the GET, POST, PUT, etc for each table

my question now is in the Global.asax.cs file at the end I have this

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetResolver
(

t =>
{
    if (t == typeof(TasksController))
    {
        return new TasksController(new TaskRepository());
    }

    return null;
},

t => new List<object>()
);
```

which initialize my dependencies, but...

first, for some reason (I think it have to do with the framework versions) the ServiceResolver class doesn't exist why?? and

second even if exist how I need to write the code to create and initialize the rest of the controllers??

```
t =>
{
    if (t == typeof(TasksController))
    {
        return new TasksController(new TaskRepository());
    }

    if (t == typeof(OtherController))
    {
        return new OtherController();
    }

    if (t == typeof(OneMoreController))
    {
        return new OneMoreController();
    }

    return null;
}
```

perhaps??

thanks for any help on this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is badly outdated. It's based on a preview release of Web API. In the final version of Web API, the correct configuration hook for dependency injection is

```cs
config.DependencyResolver = new MyDependencyResolver();

public class MyDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        // return a different instance if you want to dispose resources
        return this;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (t == typeof(TasksController))
        {
            return new TasksController(new TaskRepository());
        }

        if (t == typeof(OtherController))
        {
            return new OtherController();
        }

        if (t == typeof(OneMoreController))
        {
            return new OneMoreController();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this code should be in the global.asa file?, also where I can see this syntax? Can u point me to some docs please

Comment: Here's a great link for you: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver